# How Are Typecasts in C Implemented?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, x86, arm, instruction-set

From the perspective of an application programmer, typecasts just work. With some syntax, the unsigned representation of an integer can act as a signed integer value less than INT_MAX. What are the algorithms that perform these conversions and what are their time complexities? Are there dedicated items of modern Instruction Set Architectures that perform the conversions, or does the compiler know of a sequence of instructions? If there is platform dependence in how typecasts work internally, do these differences ever leak into the effects of a typecast?

Comment: Please try to ask one question at a time, would help you to clarify a bit yourself first.

Comment: Which of the hundreds of C compilers in the world targeting which of dozens of instruction sets are you asking about?

Answer (score 6):

The C language confuses two different processes under the same syntax of "type casting". The first is simply interpreting the same set of bits in two different ways. This is what happens, for example, when you cast a signed int to an unsigned int. Nothing actually changes, you just tell the compiler to interpret those bits in a different way. For example, the expression `a < b` might cause different code to be generated than for `a < (unsigned)b`, even though the cast itself does not actually do anything to the bits of `b` itself.

Likewise, a pointers to things can be cast to pointers to different things, but they're still just memory addresses, and the cast doesn't actually change anything other than how the compiler performs operations like pointer math and dereferencing.

The other unrelated thing that C mistakenly calls type casting is type conversion. If you have an `int a`, the expression `(double)a` will actually call a function to convert the integer to the equivalent double-precision floating point value. This involves considerable math. Converting among integer types generally leaves bits alone but adds extra bits: for example, if `short a = 0x1234`, then `(long)a` will be `0x00001234` (whether the fill bits are 0s or 1s depends on signedness).

Comment: One might reasonably take the view that C views all casts as type conversions; a type conversion from one kind of pointer to another doesn’t affect where the pointer points, and likewise a type conversion from one kind of (same sized) integer to another doesn’t affect the bit pattern at all.

Comment: But a low-level system language like C really ought to have separate functions: for example, I ought to be able to cast a float to a long and get the actual bits of the long in IEEE format. I can do that with `*((long *)(&f))`, though even that's technically a no-no.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, it is technically a crime for a reason... machines with separate memory for floating point are at least possible; machines in which the memory space includes some sort of "data descriptor" (outside of the value itself) used to exist, and it seems the idea is regaining traction...

Comment: @vonbrand Correct, that's a few of the many reasons a defined, sanctioned way of getting a float's bits would be useful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure using `memcpy()` is the officially-sanctioned way to do it. But that's stupid, which is why I don't do it that way in ojrandlib, for example.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker The officially sanctioned way of getting the bits is using a `union`.  `memcpy()` will work, but it’s likely to be much slower.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any code involved in the actual typecast. It's just reinterpreting the underlying bytes in a different way. All your typecast does is turn off the type checks in the compiler. I.e. if you write:

```
unsigned int  uInt = UINT_MAX;
int           sInt = (int)uInt;

printf( "sInt = %d\n", sInt );
```

You get -1. That's because the underlying bytes are all set to 0xff, i.e. all bits are 1. If you look at 4 bytes expecting an unsigned int, that's 4294967295, if you look at 4 bytes expecting a signed int, the same bits are interpreted as -1.

The actual data in RAM doesn't change. However, the compiler generates different machine code instructions depending on whether it thinks these 4 bytes you've given it are signed or unsigned.

Similarly, if you specify a signed or unsigned int to printf(), but use the wrong format (i.e. print an unsigned int using %d, or a signed one using %u), *printf* is the place that interprets the bytes wrongly.

The advantage of C over assembler and raw machine code is that C actually keeps track of whether a variable should be considered signed or not, and doesn't force you to remember it, and even warns you when you get it wrong. Typecasts are just a signal to the compiler that such a "doing it wrong" case is actually correct, and the compiler should just trust you that you know what you're doing.

Mind you, in C++, things are different. Typecasting between C++ classes or assigning a subclass to a variable of the base class's type may actually generate code to adjust the pointer.

**Update:** As Alastair mentioned, that's not quite true: What I wrote is only 100% true if you typecast a pointer or types of the same size. For numeric types of different size, C *will* actually generate a tiny bit of code that e.g. truncates a floating point number like 4.5 into 4, or makes sure that if you typecast the char -1 into an int, it will move the bit that indicates the sign "up". That way, you still get -1, and not 255 (which would be the interpretation of the bits that make up -1 as a char when seen as an int).

Comment: Strictly speaking, that isn’t true. e.g. `(unsigned char)0x1234` will give `0x34`, while `(int)4.35` will (depending on rounding mode) result in `4`.  Casts *may* truncate or sign extend and they may also perform a floating-point-to-integer or integer-to-floating point conversion.  All of those involve code.